# Why is there a .matplotlib folder in my home folder of Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, home-folder, matplotlib

I even do not install python. And after I delete it, it will appear after a while. So I think it was created by some other applications. Does any one has met the same problem and know why?

In addition, here is the file structure of the folder:

- .matplotlib

  - tex.cache(empty folder)
  - fontList.cache

And here are the programs I have installed:
[image: program list]

Comment: Can you post a list of programs you do have installed on the computer? One of them may require matplotlib and python and automatically (re)install it.

Comment: Did you install any kind of shell integrated thing? This sounds like the kind of thing that occurs when I install Tortoise SVN, or the Git stuff, etc. Installing Python might have installed a similar shell extension, and simply deleting the Python folder wouldn't have been enough to remove it. If you download and use Autoruns.exe or similar you can see and disable installed extensions.